# How to make a batch script to unzip a password protected .zip file without additional zip tools?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, batch-file, unzip

What I had in mind was to prompt the user to for a password, then attempt to unzip a .zip file with it. Is it possible without using additional tools like 7-zip and WinRAR? I know you can call `:UnZipFile` to extract a .zip file, but how can I do this with a password protected one?

Comment: In Powershell 5 it is much easier now to zip and unzip files but it also does not provide a native solution for password protected zip files.

Comment: with 7zip which is free for commercial use
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320128/how-to-unzip-password-protected-file-using-batch-script-via-7zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in zip capability in Windows 7 CMD environment does not support extracting password-protected ZIP files.

You will have to use an "additional tool", and I recommend 7zip, a generally capable, reliable, and open source compression utility.

Comment: Well, I don't know, because I noticed that there was a feature in explorer.exe that allows you to extract password protected .zip files. I thought you could just call this from powershell or something. Anyways, you're probably right. I'll just automatically download and use 7za.exe in my batch script then. Thanks! :)